# Disable other checkboxes once the first one is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I am building multiple checkboxes. I want to add the functionality that if the first answer is Yes (Did data reach ? Ans: Yes), all the remaining checkboxes are disabled. How should I go about doing that ?

**HTML:**

```
<p><span>Did data reach?</span>
   <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkme1" value="Yes" />
     Yes
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkme2" value="No" />
     No
   </form>
 </p>
 <p>
   <span>Is time right?</span>

   <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme3" value="Yes" />
      Yes
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme4" value="No" />
      No
   </form>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Is order complete?</span>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme5" value="Yes" />
      Yes
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme6" value="No" /> 
      No
    </form>
  </p>
```

**JS:**

```
 var checker1 = document.getElementById('checkme1');
 var checker2 = document.getElementById('checkme2');
 var checker3 = document.getElementById('checkme3');
 var checker4 = document.getElementById('checkme4');
 var checker5 = document.getElementById('checkme5');
 var checker6 = document.getElementById('checkme6');
 // when unchecked or checked, run the function
 checker1.onchange = function(){
if(this.checked){
    checkme1.disabled = false;
} else {
    checkme2.disabled = false;
} else {
    checkme3.disabled = true;
} else {
    checkme4.disabled = true;
} else {
    checkme5.disabled = true;
} else {
    checkme6.disabled = true;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

More than one `else` case is invalid syntax. You want a single `if` that includes code to disable all of the other checkboxes, followed by a single `else` that includes code to (re)enable all of the other checkboxes:

```
if(this.checked){
    checkme2.disabled = true;
    checkme3.disabled = true;
    checkme4.disabled = true;
    checkme5.disabled = true;
    checkme6.disabled = true;
} else {
    checkme2.disabled = false;
    checkme3.disabled = false;
    checkme4.disabled = false;
    checkme5.disabled = false;
    checkme6.disabled = false;
}
```

Or you can shorten that by leaving out the if/else altogether:

```
checkme2.disabled = this.checked;
checkme3.disabled = this.checked;
checkme4.disabled = this.checked;
checkme5.disabled = this.checked;
checkme6.disabled = this.checked;
```

Or one statement:

```
checker2.disabled
  = checker3.disabled
  = checker4.disabled
  = checker5.disabled
  = checker6.disabled
  = this.checked;
```

Or, one line of jQuery (that doesn't require any of the `checkmeX` variables):

```
$("#checkme1").click(function() {
  $(":checkbox").not(this).prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

(Expand and run the following to see it working with your html.)

```js
$("#checkme1").click(function() {
  $(":checkbox").not(this).prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span>Did data reach?</span>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkme1" value="Yes" />Yes
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkme2" value="No" />No</form>
</p>
<p><span>Is time right?</span>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkme3" value="Yes" />Yes
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkme4" value="No" />No</form>
</p>
<p><span>Is order complete?</span>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkme5" value="Yes" />Yes
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkme6" value="No" />No</form>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
<p><span>Did data reach?</span>
   <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkme1" class='parent'  value="Yes" />
     Yes
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkme2" class='child'  value="No" />
     No
   </form>
 </p>
 <p>
   <span>Is time right?</span>

   <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme3" class='child' value="Yes" />
      Yes
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme4" class='child' value="No" />
      No
   </form>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Is order complete?</span>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme5" class='child' value="Yes" />
      Yes
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkme6" class='child' value="No" /> 
      No
    </form>
  </p>
```

Then use following javascript:-

```
function toggleCheckboxState(className, diabled) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i)
  {
      checkboxes[i].disabled  = diabled
  }
}
document.getElementById('checkme2').onclick = function(e) {
    var diabled  = false
  if(this.checked) {
        diabled = true
  }
  toggleCheckboxState('parent', diabled)
}

document.getElementById('checkme1').onclick = function(e) {
    var diabled  = false
  if(this.checked) {
        diabled = true
  }

  toggleCheckboxState('child', diabled)
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oa2npkat/1//)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkme1").change(function(e) {

    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("input[id^='checkme']").prop("disabled", "true");
      $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("input[id^='checkme']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Did data reach?</span>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkme1" value="Yes" />Yes
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkme2" value="No" />No
</form>
<span>Is time right?</span>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkme3" value="Yes" />Yes
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkme4" value="No" />No
</form>
<span>Is order complete?</span>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkme5" value="Yes" />Yes
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkme6" value="No" />No
</form>
```