# How to disable/unable checkboxes in the table after one of the checkboxes is clicked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, disabled-control

I have a table with checkboxes.

I need to disable all the textboxes except of the one selected.

So far I highlight the raw with selected checkbox:

```
$("#tblMerchantNotes").on("click", ":checkbox", function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor', $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color'));
        $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', 'yellow')
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parents("tr:first").css('background-color', $(this).parents("tr:first").data('prevColor'));
    }    
});
```

The table in the above code is a datatable built from a webservice call:

```
Web.Services.MerchantService.GetMerchantNotes(merchant.MerchantID, function (result) {
MerchantNotes = [];
     for (var ctr = 0; ctr < result.length; ctr++) {
          var item = result[ctr];
          var checked = ' ';
          if (item.Important) checked = "checked";
          var id = item.ID;
                  
          MerchantNotes[MerchantNotes.length] =
          [
            <input type="checkbox" class="importantNoteCheck" ' + checked + ' ">',
            item.CreatedDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
            item.CreatedBy,
            item.CategoryName == null ? '' : item.CategoryName,
            item.Note,
            item.ApplicationName,
            '<input type="button" class="updateMerchantNote" id=' + item.ID + ' value="Update" onclick="MerchantDetailManager.UpdateMerchantNote(' + item.ID + ')">'
                    ];
                }
            $('#tblMerchantNotes').dataTable().fnClearTable();
            if (MerchantNotes.length>0)
            $('#tblMerchantNotes').dataTable().fnAddData(MerchantNotes);
 });
```

And these are a couple of rows generated as an html:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="importantNoteCheck" "=""></td>
</tr>
...some more rows
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="importantNoteCheck" "=""></td>
</tr>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Where's your HTML as part of the question?  And/or a working example?

Comment: This is a datatable I build from a call to a webservice

Comment: Okay. And presumably it creates an HTML table structure, which you have not provided.

Comment: The HTML table is large, so I provided a couple of rows.

Comment: I searched for "*jquery uncheck all other checkboxes*" and found many, *many* answers.  You'll need to show us the ones you've already tried, and let us know why they don't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Uncheck other checkbox on one checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785010/jquery-uncheck-other-checkbox-on-one-checked)

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I need to disable not to uncheck all the checkboxes except of the checked or unchecked one

Comment: OK ... so did you try searching for "*jquery disable all other checkboxes*"? There are many answers if you do, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122204/disable-other-checkboxes-once-the-first-one-is-enabled).  Instead of `....prop('checked', false)` you do `....prop('disabled', true)`.  Does that help?